# To update p-chart on binding data from db using angular

Tags: angular, primeng

TS File:
 I am making a service call to get quarters and different business lines and the number of people mapped to that business line. But,while populating my x-axis shows same business multiple times and takes value of other business line in it.
I want y-axis with count of people and on x-axis business lines. These all should get populated when i select an option from dropwdown.

Comment: Would like to see some code

Comment: please share some code snippet to understand your problem